# Can I install Xcode 4.2 on OSX 10.6.8 (Snow Leopard)?

Tags: ios4, xcode4.2

My Mac has snow leopard version 10.6.8. I have installed Xcode 3.2.5, can I update to xcode 4.2 with my present OS version?

Comment: -1 for low quality question that the OP could've answered him/herself with a quick trip to [iTunes](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/xcode/id497799835?ls=1&mt=12]).

Comment: Disagree with the -1.  This issue of Xcode is a sore one: both answers are found, with apparently the fact that the paid developer account has access to it.  It is a relevant question, even moreso the consequences: does it upgrade gracefully?  Could be nasty for a production server that relies on xcode tools...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, not possible, you need the latest version of Mac OSX: Snow Lion (10.8) to run xCode 4.2.
Luckily, the upgrade isn't that expensive, and is said to be worth the money (have bought the upgrade already, but not installed it myself :-) )

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can. 4.2 is the last XCode version that supports Snow Leopard, you'll need a later OS version to use anything newer. You'll need a developer account to download it from Apple however. I'm not saying that you NEED to download it from Apple though. I leave the rest to your imagination.